# Laravel 5: Add value to fields in Form model

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

Hello I have a form in laravel opened in model form

```
{!! Form::model($issue, ['url' => 'calidad/issues/' . $issue->id, 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
```

In the form i have some fields stored in a table as $key (name of the field) and $value (value of the field).

I can get the fields values with:

```
$issue->source()->get()
```

and this return a collection with the rows.

So my question is, how can i put this values in the form in a simple way.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in an easy way - the `Form::model()` construct was never made with this complexity in mind. You could put some custom accessors that access this internal structure on your model and it may work, but it may be a bit too complex for you to really bother with.

Comment: Could you show the code for the rest of your form please

Comment: My form is really big, like 90-100 fields, but here you have a sample

          {!! Form::text('2-auditor', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => '2-auditor'))!!}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a temporary solution with Blade + JQuery + php

In the controller y get the fields and i put them into an array

```
    $input = $issue->source()->get()->lists('value','key');
```

And I filled the fields with this:

```
@foreach($input as $key => $value)
    $("#{!!$key!!}").val("{!!$value!!}");
@endforeach
```

I cant think in anything else but this works.